# How to find which masterpage we are using in sharepoint 2013 Website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

There are lot of Masterpages available in out sharepoint designer, I want to update something in our current masterpage, but I'm unable to find which one we are using now.

I tried to click right click on masterpage and check set as default option is not getting on which masterpage, but it's showing that option to more than 6 masterpages, So is there any other simple way to find??

Suggestions will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Hit following URL in your browser.

```
{site url}/_api/web?$select=CustomMasterUrl,MasterUrl
```

You will get following response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xml:base="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sm/_api/">
   <id>https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sm/_api/Web</id>
   <category term="SP.Web" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
   <link rel="edit" href="Web" />
   <title />
   <updated>2016-11-09T06:23:12Z</updated>
   <author>
      <name />
   </author>
   <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
         <d:CustomMasterUrl>/sites/sm/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master</d:CustomMasterUrl>
         <d:MasterUrl>/sites/sm/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master</d:MasterUrl>
      </m:properties>
   </content>
</entry>
```

Now check the value of `d:CustomMasterUrl` and `<d:MasterUrl>`

## OR

Make a GET request using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) REST Client to above URL. It will show response in JSON format.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also run this simple Powershell script to check the masterpage in use:

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
 $site = Get-SPSite http://yourSiteUrl/
 $web = $site.RootWeb
 $web.CustomMasterUrl
 $web.MasterUrl
 $web.AlternateCssUrl
```

Comment: Dear sir, thanks for your response.

I tried using powershell, but it's showing an error and also saying you dont have enough permissions to check this ,,etc.

So please if you have any idea without powershell kindly tell me.

Comment: try running Powershell ISE as an administrator ! @Asrar Rightclick on Powershell ISE and select Run as Administrator.

Comment: did,but still same error :(

Comment: The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.

getting the above error

Comment: You can also do it from designer Go to masterpages folder and click on any of masterpage.master. If the masterpage is in use then the Set as Default masterpage and Set as custom masterpage will be disabled. Either or both. But if it is not in use either or both the buttons can be used to change the masterpage.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was resolved by right clicking and running as administrator!! @Asrar

Comment: You can add your name as SP shell admin and try running to do that use this command:                                                                                                        `Add-SPShellAdmin -username DOMAIN\YourUser`

Comment: if you are getting this error **You need to have machine administrator privileges to run this cmdlet**  then **run the shell as an administrator with the run as administrator option.**

Comment: {site url}/_api/web?$select=CustomMasterUrl,MasterUrl

this is working fine :)

Thank you so much for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a **Publishing site** you can go in setting.aspx page

```
under look and feel -> Master page
```

You find the which page is applied.

If it is a **Team site** you browse  with following url

```
http://<your site>/_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx
```

Comment: Dear sir, Thanks for your response,It's a public facing website
I have checked in look and feel, it's showing "for site masterpage= "Coaf" and for syterm masterpage inherits from="seatile"

now I went to the designer and right clicked on the coaf masterpage it's showing set as default masterpage option, my question is if it's our current masterpage then why it's showing that option??

Comment: Because custom master page is site master page used for publishing pages only and default master page is system master page,. That the reason "Coaf" is still have a option enable to set it default.